# Mocked function getting overwritten in class

Tags: c#, moq

I have a class that implements DocRaptor's pdf creator

```
public class PdfCreator {
  public byte[] createPdf(string html){
      int tryCount = 3;
      while(tryCount > 0) {
          try {
            Configuration.Default.Username = "YOUR_API_KEY_HERE"; // this key works for test documents
            DocApi docraptor = new DocApi();

            Doc doc = new Doc(
                // create a new doc object
            );

            AsyncDoc response = docraptor.CreateAsyncDoc(doc);

            AsyncDocStatus status_response;

            Boolean done = false;

            while(!done) {
                // Mocked this but it's getting ovewritten with a different StatusId
                status_response = docraptor.GetAsyncDocStatus(response.StatusId);

                Console.WriteLine("doc status: " + status_response.Status);
                switch(status_response.Status) {
                case "completed":
                    done = true;
                    byte[] doc_response = docraptor.GetAsyncDoc(status_response.DownloadId);
                    File.WriteAllBytes("/tmp/docraptor-csharp.pdf", doc_response);
                    Console.WriteLine("Wrote PDF to /tmp/docraptor-csharp.pdf");
                    break;
                case "failed":
                    done = true;
                    Console.WriteLine("FAILED");
                    Console.WriteLine(status_response);
                    break;
                default:
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (DocRaptor.Client.ApiException error) {
            if (--tryCount == 0) throw;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In my test, I'm trying to force it to fail and throw exception in the catch block by mokcing the `GetAsyncDocStatus` call to return a status of `failed`

```
_docRaptorService.Setup(p => p.GetAsyncDocStatus(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns("failed");

var docRaptor = new PdfCreator();

string html = $"<html><body><h1>Hello World!</h1></body></html>";

byte[] doc = docRaptor.createPdf(html);

_docRaptorService.Verify(p => p.GetAsyncDocStatus(It.IsAny<string>()), Times.Once);
```

But when I run the test the test fails saying the method was not called. And if I run the test in debug mode, the `GetAsyncDocStatus` returns `completed` instead of `failed`, which makes me think the class is not using the mocked version of the method. How can I solve this?

Comment: is `GetAsyncDocStatus` virtual?

Comment: No it's not virtual

Comment: make it virtual that way moq can do its thing.

Comment: You're instantiating `docraptor` in the method you're testing. So the mock instance you're creating isn't being used. Can you show the entirety of the class and the test?

Comment: @devNull Whatever I posted is the full version of the class/test

Comment: You'll need to actually use the mock instance of `DocApi` in your method. Which is usually done through dependency injection. The SO post above describes it more

Comment: Ah alright. So I should use DI and use the IDoc interface instead of instantiating the `DocApi` class. Will give it a go and let  you know how it goes.

Comment: @devNull That worked, but even when it hits the `failed` state, it's still not going to the `catch` block. I think I need to simulate a timeout for it to enter that block. Any ideas?

Comment: @ZeroDarkThirty well you don't manually throw an exception in the "failed" case, so I wouldn't expect the catch block to be hit. It sounds like you just want to mock an exception be thrown from `GetAsyncDocStatus`. If so, you can see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10323930/5803406) on how that's done

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213588/discussion-between-zerodarkthirty-and-devnull).

Answer (score 0):

The below implementation is working fine for me.
Removed some parts of the code as the intention here is just to make sure the mock is working as expected.
Used `method injection` for `Dependency Injection`, any type of `DI` can be used like `constructor`, `property` etc.

```
public class PdfCreator
{
    public byte[] CreatePdf(string html, IDocApi docraptor)
    {
        try
        {           

            Boolean done = false;

            while (!done)
            {
                // Mocked this but it's getting ovewritten with a different StatusId
                var status_response = docraptor.GetAsyncDocStatus("testInput");

                Console.WriteLine("doc status: " + status_response);
                switch (status_response)
                {
                    case "completed":
                        done = true;
                        byte[] doc_response = docraptor.GetAsyncDoc("DownloadId");
                        File.WriteAllBytes("/tmp/docraptor-csharp.pdf", doc_response);
                        Console.WriteLine("Wrote PDF to /tmp/docraptor-csharp.pdf");
                        break;
                    case "failed":
                        done = true;
                        Console.WriteLine("FAILED");
                        Console.WriteLine(status_response);
                        break;
                    default:
                        Thread.Sleep(1000);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }

        return new byte[1];
    }
}

public interface IDocApi
{
    string GetAsyncDocStatus(string docId);
    byte[] GetAsyncDoc(string downloadId);
}

public class DocApi : IDocApi
{
    public byte[] GetAsyncDoc(string downloadId)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public string GetAsyncDocStatus(string docId)
    {
        return "completed";
    }
}
```

In unit test mocked the IDocApi interface and injected it through the method.

```
 [TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void CreatePdfMethodGetAsyncDocStatusShouldReturnFailed()
    {
        Mock<IDocApi> mockDocApi = new Mock<IDocApi>();

        mockDocApi.Setup(m => m.GetAsyncDocStatus(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns("failed");

        PdfCreator sut = new PdfCreator();

        sut.CreatePdf("dummyHtml", mockDocApi.Object);

        //not asserting 
    }
}
```

Working screenshot
[image]